# D3 - add class to selected parent

Tags: d3.js

I have a demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/basic-bar-mt-3msgqg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbar-chart.ts)

It's a simple D3 bar chart in an angular app.

I want to check if the x-axis text has 'Feb' in it.

If it does I want to add a class to the parent g

```
<g class="tick CLASS ADDED HERE" opacity="1" transform="translate(42.77777777777778,0)">
    <line stroke="#000" y2="6"></line>
    <text fill="red" y="16" dy="0.71em">Feb</text>
</g>
```

I can detect the text and style it but I would like a class added to the parent g

```
private accessTicks() {
      d3.selectAll(".x-axis text")
        .filter(d => d === 'Feb')
        .attr("fill", 'red')
        //d3.selectAll(this.previousSibling)
        //.attr('class', '')
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what your need:

```
...
private accessTicks() {
  let selection = d3.selectAll(".x-axis text")
      .filter((d) => {  return d === 'Feb'})
      .attr("fill", 'red')

    // this will allow you to select the parent of your selected element.
    let selectionParent = selection.select(function () {
      console.log(this.parentNode);
      return this.parentNode
    });

    selectionParent.classed("feb-parent", true);
}
...
```

**Update**:
Fixed the duplicate issue, my previous code was overriding the tick classList attribute, now I'm adding new class instead.

Comment: This solution duplicates the tick and the text when the window is resized - https://stackblitz.com/edit/basic-bar-mt-2wi5uj?file=src/app/bar-chart.ts

Comment: @cdmt, I updated my code and fixed the duplicate issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/basic-bar-mt-gp9vuk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbar-chart.ts